# why $this->facebook->getUser(); returns 0?

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

i've tried everything.
i changed my domain to other than localhost.

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller Extends CI_Controller
{
    var $data;
    var $master;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->data = array();
        $this->master = "layout/master";

        parse_str( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_REQUEST );
        $CI = & get_instance();
        $CI->config->load("facebook",TRUE);
        $config = $CI->config->item('facebook');
        $this->load->library('Facebook', $config);

        $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

        if ($user == 0)
            $this->data['login_url'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "user_about_me"));
        else{
            $user = $this->facebook->api('/me');
            $this->data['logout_url'] = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl();
        }
        print_r($user);
        print_r($this->facebook->getAccessToken());
    }
}
```

Why do i success to obtain the AccessToken, but $user still return 0?
i searched all over stackoverflow and google.

facebook success to redirect me back to my site, if i was not clear..

Comment: Are you sure it does not return `false`? The `($user==0)` does not mean that `$user` is zero. The expression just means that `$user` evaluates to `false`. Before the `if` block try this: `var_dump($user);die;`

Comment: it doesn't die. echo $user returns 0;

Comment: I am assuming [this is the source](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L544) for the plugin you are using, and it returns `0` *"if the signed request didn't present a user id"*. It is probably because your configuration is not correct.

Comment: in-facebook configuration or appId&secret configuration? :P

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/ i think it is something within the last update of july, 2013

Comment: the site is not redirecting when $user is 0 but redirect is required. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Tweaking your code

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->data = array();
    $this->master = "layout/master";

    parse_str( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_REQUEST );
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->config->load("facebook",TRUE);
    $config = $CI->config->item('facebook');
    $this->load->library('Facebook', $config);
}

function facebook_login()
{    

    $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

    if($user == 0){

        $loginUrl = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope"=>"user_about_me"));
        redirect("$loginUrl","location");

    } else {

        $user_info = $this->facebook->api('/me');
        print_r($user_info);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a good few hours trying many fixes and noticed my domain was set to `http://domain.co.uk` in facebook whereas the `getLoginUrl` was directing to `http://www.domain.co.uk`.